# Using data tables from themes E.g. Front theme

Tags: model-view-controller, datatables, web-frontend

How do I use this data table with mvc to get my data from the controller to the view:

```
<script>
   $(document).on('ready', function () {
     // initialization of datatables
          $.HSCore.components.HSDatatables.init('.js-datatable');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all classes and div wrappers are in acquisition.